# Can an Airbnb host insist on credit card information upon arrival?

Tags: payment-cards, airbnb

I reserved a room on Airbnb, confirmed by the host through written messages on Airbnb's system.  Nothing about a credit card was mentioned.

Upon my arrival, they showed me the room, which was fine, and they said that they require to have my credit card on file, which will only be charged in case of damage to the room.

Since it was late and I was tired and they already had many positive reviews, I just accepted it.  (This was some time ago, and fortunately I still haven't had any trouble with my credit card since then.)

Is this acceptable under Airbnb terms of service?  What should I have done in this situation?

Answer (score 6):

From AirBnB Q&A:

> If a host asks you for more money than what you paid on the site and
>   the extra charge wasn’t stated in the listing or in the message
>   thread, you can dispute the charges in the [Resolution Center](https://www.airbnb.ie/help/article/767). **Never
>   pay a host directly for these charges.**

and [also](https://www.airbnb.ie/help/article/458/can-a-security-deposit-be-collected-outside-of-the-airbnb-website)

> Can a security deposit be collected outside of the Airbnb website?
>
> No. To make sure guest payments are protected and to ensure that hosts
>   are properly compensated for reservation damages, we ask that all
>   security deposits be handled through the Airbnb website. **Payments
>   outside of the Airbnb website, including security deposits, are a
>   violation of our [Terms of Service](https://www.airbnb.ie/terms)**.

The host can [make a claim ony your security deposit via airbnb](https://www.airbnb.ie/help/article/352/what-happens-if-a-host-makes-a-claim-on-my-security-deposit), he doesn't need your card.

Comment: Makes sense. But what would I actually say or do to enforce that?

Comment: you can deny to give your credit card and refer to the Terms of Service. If there are any problems I would contact airbnb and they should help you.